# JQuery: дождаться ответа от

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день.
Есть вот такой код https://jsfiddle.net/bst604jz/5/
Это упрощенная версия моего рабочего. Суть простая `formValidate` выполняет валидацию формы перед отправкой. Там обычная проверка на пустые поля. Но кроме этого необходимо сделать запрос на сервер, который возвращает или OK или FAIL. Если ответ OK - форму можно отправить. Если FAIL - форму не сабмиттим и выводим ошибку. При вызове этого кода

```
formValidate(clb);
  if(valid) {
    console.log('1');
  };
return false;
```

`clb` выполняется, но проверка на `valid` возвращает `false` и только после этого оно становится true. И со второго сабмита формы все сработает как нужно. Собственно вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы при обработке submit'а можно было дождаться ответа от get запроса и только потом проверить условие?

Comment: все свои условия прокидывай в колбеки и все. Ну либо создай промисы

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев тут более сложный вопрос - ему же нужно принять решение внутри обработчика события!

Comment: Имеет смысл просто послать форму на сервер, там проверить все условия и вернуть ошибку или ОК

Comment: В таком случае во время submit'a с валидацией, надо возвращать `false`, а из callback'а при благоприятном ответе с сервера снова вызывать submit, но валидацию уже не делать и возвращать `true`.

Comment: Нет, именно этого я пытаюсь избежать. Суть в том, что форма принимает крупные файлы, то есть человеку надо ждать, пока все загрузится, чтобы узнать, что капча, к примеру, невалидна. А я хочу проверять это до отправки всех данных на сервер

Comment: Хм, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form.submit();` - не вызывает обработчик события submit назначенный с помощью jQuery.

```
//check
$('#mform').on('submit', function() {
  var form = this;
  formValidate(callback);
  return false;

  function callback(result) {
    if(!result) { 
      alert('Капча невалидна');
    } else {
      form.submit();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Э... зачем делать внутри clb то, что уже сделано внутри formValidate автором?..

Comment: $("#mform")[0].submit(); - вот этот кусочек оказался тем, что я сам упустил, пытался вызывать $("#mform").submit(); и падал в цикл :) Кажется это то, что нужно, сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: Исправил ваш код, чтобы он соответствовал задумке автора вопроса.